# Realm - filter words with accents

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm to my Android project, I want to type for example "avion" and tell realm to look also for "avión" word, "avión" is in English "airplane".

This is an example that I've implemented:

**querySearched: Variable that contains the word I typed.**

```
realm.where(Offer.class).contains("detailedDescription", querySearched,
                Case.INSENSITIVE).or().contains("name", querySearched, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                .or().contains("company.name", querySearched, Case.INSENSITIVE).not().equalTo("viewType", 1).findAll()
                .sort(new String[]{Constants.ISFROMWORLD,Constants.VIEWTYPE, Constants.PREFERENTOFFER,
                                Constants.LEVEL, Constants.EXPIRINGDATE},
                        new Sort[]{Sort.DESCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.DESCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING})
```

To be specific I want that if I type for example "avion" I want to realm to look for "avión".

Comment: It might be easier to sanitize your string before passing it into the query

Comment: If you are required to keep the exact strings without sanitizing, what you you can do, is either maintain a dictionary of "synonyms" (if the their number is known) or you can generate the "synonyms" if the rules are known (e.g. o -> ó is one rule). Another solution is to keep to strings - sanitized one for search purposes and unsanitized one for show purposes.

Comment: I always add a second field that contains the word as lower-case accentless string, and query against *that*. It works against `árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép` which was pretty much my requirement.